# C# Runtime Label not displaying full string

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a C# winform that is a weekly planner and I am converting a list of events to string. The event class includes 2 string properties that I want to be added to my string array so I can print it to my Monday tab. I can see that the 2 string properties get added to the array as i use Debug to print the string array, but for some reason when build the label i only get the first word.

For example if the title was "Doctors Appointment" and the Description was "Dr sam". The only thing that would show on the label is "Doctors".

My code:

```
private void UpdateWeeklyPlanner()
{
    string[] eventsInfo = monday.GetEvents().Select(x => $"{x.Title}, {x.Description}").ToArray();

    foreach(var s in eventsInfo)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(s);
        Label label = new Label();
        label.Text = s;
        label.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        label.Parent = tabMonday;
        tabMonday.Controls.Add(label);

    } 
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the Label wide enough to show all the text? Do you need to enable `AutoSize`?

Answer (score 0):

Set this property.

```
label.AutoSize = true;
```